# How to get EF Core to mark ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate properties as IsTemporary

Tags: ef-core-2.2

I have a property `CreatedUtc` on my entities that has SQL default value of `SYSUTCDATETIME()`. Using Fluent Api, I have the property marked as `ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate()` to signal EF that the value is computed. I tried using `ValueGeneratedOnAdd()`. I also tried setting the property as DateTime and DateTime? in combination with my fluent decorations. In all cases, the property is marked `IsTemporary = false` by EF Core.

I am trying to use this for my Audit code. I need EF Core to set `CreatedUtc` as `IsTemporary = true` so my audit will write it after the initial save, when all temporary properties get their actual values. As I would expect, my identity property is correctly marked IsTemporary since EF knows it's definitely database generated.

I am aware that setting `ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate()` does not exclusively mean that the value is database generated, and therefore would not necessarily be a legitimate temporary property. But, it seems like this would be a needed piece in getting to the end goal of the property getting marked as temporary.

Does anyone know how to get EF Core to set non-identity computed properties (such as `CreatedUtc`) as IsTemporary?

Note: I have not tried any manual setting of IsTemporary. If that is option, at what point would I be able to set that?

Here if my fluent configuration of a `CreatedUtc` instance:

```
builder.Property(e => e.CreatedUtc)
       .HasDefaultValueSql("(sysutcdatetime())")
       .ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();
```